# Orthogonal Projection and Inner Product Space

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

Prove:

Let V be an inner product space. $W⊂V$ and $v∈V$.

Let $w∈W$ be an orthogonal projection. Then for every $u∈W ; ||w-v||<= ||u-v||$.

I really do not have a clue on how to solve this.

Comment: does $V$ has finite dimension ?

Comment: This is usually the definition of projection of $v$ onto $W$.

Comment: Yes, V has a finite dimension.

Comment: How do you define the orthogonal projection from $V$ onto $W$?